# Mongoose finds empty array when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find a `SoldProduct` with `intimeOrderNumber` equal to `'3'`.

```
var query = { intimeOrderNumber: '3' };
```

But I get an empty array.

```
SoldProduct.find(query, function(err, soldProducts) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(soldProducts.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < soldProducts.length; i++) {
      if (soldProducts[i].intimeOrderNumber === '3') {
        console.log(typeof soldProducts[i].intimeOrderNumber);
        console.log(soldProducts[i].intimeOrderNumber);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Output:

```
0
```

But when I change the `query` like this:

```
var query = {};
```

and run the same `find`, it's evident that there actually **is** a `SoldProduct` with `intimeOrderNumber` equal to `'3'` in the database because the output changes to:

```
15
string
3
```

I have `intimeOrderNumber: String` in the `SoldProduct` model definition. Why does the first query return an empty array?

Comment: When you run `db.yourcollection.find({intimeOrderNumber: '3'})`, from `mongodb` console, does it return the document you expect?

Comment: No, of course it doesn't. I was sure I had tried that...

Comment: Sorry @Zabri, I didn't meant to be rude. I just asked because the `intimeOrderNumber` attribute might be stored as a `Number`. So, if you search with `db.yourcollection.find({intimeOrderNumber: 3})`, does it work?

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean my comment sarcastically. I really thought I had tried that, but obviously I hadn't. Your comment pointed me to the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fact that I had been adding the `intimeOrderNumber`s to the DB directly through the MongoDB console and I accidentally added `Number`s instead of `String`s.

So when looking for the document, `'3'` did not match `3`, so it didn't find it. But when I found it with that empty query, the `intimeOrderNumber` somehow got converted to a `String` because that's the way it was set in the model.